# How do I figure out which of these stock buying fees best benefits early buyers.

Tags: economics, percentages

I'm trying to make a game that's kind of like buying stocks. The property value / price goes up a random amount over time. You can buy or sell a share for the current value.

Since the prices only ever go up, there needs to be a fee introduced to add risk. I am trying to figure out if the fee should be charged when you buy, when you sell, or both.

I want buying early to be more beneficial than buying later. An increase from 100 to 1100 should be much better than if you bought at 1000 and sold for 2000. Higher prices should have higher risks.

The main problem is that if you buy at 10 then sell for 1010, you make 1000. If you buy at 1000 and sell for 2000, you still make $1000. But it's much rarer for one you buy at 10 to go up 1000 than one already at 2000, so I want to factor in that risk by way of charging fees.

Anyone have any ideas? Sorry if this is too open ended.

Comment: Can you only buy one of each stock? Because in my book, an increase from $10$ to $1010$ is miles better than one from $1000$ to $2000$; the latter is a 100% increase in value, while the former is a 10,000% increase. With the first stock being cheaper, I'll likely buy much more of it than of the latter stock. I suppose that would be the incentive - buying early = buying cheap, and buying cheap = more stock = more profit.

Comment: Yeah you can buy multiple. The problem is that in my weird system, the price of the stock never goes down, so there has to be a fee or you'd never lose money. Higher ones are more likely to keep climbing so there would be no reason to invest in one that's really low, since if they went up the same amount you'd make the same amount. 10 shares at 10 would be the same as 1 at 100 if the stock price went up the same amount. And since stocks with higher prices are more likely to keep going up, why buy lower stocks? I'm kinda confusing myself just talking about it so there's a chance I'm wrong.

Comment: It really depends on how the stock value grows over time. If it's linear, so you have a flat increase over time per stock unit, you definitely want to buy lots of small stocks to capitalise on that. If it's exponential, then the rate of increase is proportional to the stock's value, so it doesn't really matter which you buy, as they're increasing at the same rate. Basically, once you've decided how likely a stock is to increase on any day with regards to its current value, then you can work out what a rational buyer's strategy is, and design your fees etc. accordingly.